# Match Exec failing to execute anything

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-config

Testing out the [SSH `Match Exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) feature. I have this minimal `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Match Exec echo
   ServerAliveInterval 60
```

and I am running

```
ssh localhost
```

I get

```
Unable to execute 'echo': No such file or directory
```

This is true regardless of whether I use a full path or not, or using quotes whether double or single. I tried putting a fake `echo` script in my `.ssh` folder as well. I have tried multiple commands (`test, nc, connect`). It seems the `Exec` feature cannot see my path at all.

I am running WSL Debian with OpenSSH. My final goal is to test if `$http_proxy` is reachable in the match clause in order to automate proxy usage, but getting the above to work would be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the `SHELL` environment variable to the full path of your shell, not simply to `bash` or `zsh`.

Try:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash ssh user@host
```

Answer (score 11):

To invoke "match" directives, ssh actually invokes:

```
$SHELL -c 'command'
```

"$SHELL" is either the value of the SHELL environment variable or a default which is usually "/bin/sh". "command" is the command from the "match" directive. Here is the [actual code that executes the command](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/dc38236ab6827dec575064cac65c8e7035768773/readconf.c#L549-L555):

```c
    argv[0] = shell;
    argv[1] = "-c";
    argv[2] = xstrdup(cmd);
    argv[3] = NULL;

    execv(argv[0], argv);
    error("Unable to execute '%.100s': %s", cmd, strerror(errno));
```

Note that `execv()` doesn't search any kind of path for the shell being executed, so SHELL has to be a complete pathname like "/bin/bash" or "/usr/local/bin/zsh".

If the shell had started up and then failed to run "echo", then you'd get an error from the shell. But the error that you're getting is from ssh. This implies that the problem is with invoking the shell, not with the "echo" command.

The simplest explanation is that your SHELL environment variable is invalid. It refers to a file which is missing, or it's in a directory that you can't read.

Comment: Thanks, but my `SHELL` variable is `bash`. I was looking whether SSH configuration somehow overwrites it. Both `$SHELL -c echo` and `/bin/sh -c echo` work fine.

Comment: If your SHELL is just “bash”, that’s the problem. It should be the full path to the program, eg “/bin/bash” as in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the answer. I never really noticed the variable was relative until now.